# Increment a number with a decrementing multiplier N times and have sum total always be equal to X?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(a working semi-related decrement function)

[T]500 = [T]500 * [S]0.156048361
= [N1] (134.8206296 * [M]0.85)
= [N2] (114.5975351 * [M]0.85)
= [N3] (97.40790487 * [M]0.85)
= [N4] (82.79671914 * [M]0.85) 
= 70.37721127

In this case T = 500 , N = 4,  M = 0.85 , S = 0.156048361 = (0.85-1)/0.85^(4+1)-1)

T = Total
N = is how many times you want to decrement.
M = is the multiplier
S = a number you start to decrement = (M-1)/(M^(N+1)-1)

This is possible through the sheer helpfulness of other on stackexchange. I'm an indie game dev. And this is awesome for any kind of numerical progression you want to have a boundary. Such as damage scales, loot scales, expenses etc.

The S calculation assured my results were accurate regardless of how much i fiddled with T, N and M.

### **Now the goal is:**

Increment a number that gets added X(always the same amount), N times and then multiplied N times(the same N) via linearly decrementing M multiplier and keep the SUM total a specified number. The S calculation for the decrement formula/point provides that kind of preservation of the sum total.

As far as I understand the variable that needs to be calculated for this is the how much the multiplier decrements since i want to be able to adjust the initial value.

This way if i have contraption that produces stuff with a flat value + % of the stuff it has i can tweak the base criteria enough so that it produces half its limit for the third of its time table and have it diminished later.

I can make up the numbers manually and have them add up but I've always wanted a way to do this kind of thing, with actual math.

I assume this looks something like this (you can see i'm not great at it)
:

[T]100000 = ( [S]0 + [F]500) * [MS]3 ) = ( [R1]1500 + [F]500 ) * [MS]3 * [MD]?

Where 
MS*MD = MR

Continue by doing N Times:

(R2 + F) * MR1

(R3 + F) * MR2

Legend:

T = Total
S = Start
F = Flat value to add every time
MS = Starting multiplier
MD = Multiplier decriment
MS * MD = MR

............
Even if you don't calculate it an assessment how doable and/or hard it is - works.

Comment: First off, your second line is tremendously hideous.  The equality sign has very low operation priority, understand that $x = 1 + 2$ should be read $x = (1+2)$, not $(x=1)+2$.  So for your second line, I read $500 = 70.37721127$.  I did not have the courage to read must of the remaining.

Comment: Your formula for the value $S$ is correct and comes from the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. One note: in your description of $S$, you have a formula containing a value $C$, which I believe should be $N$.

Comment: @TimThayer yes messed it up - fixed thx.

Comment: @helena4 I thought you rushed to write down the computation, not giving much care to how you presented you maths.  Now you've split up one equality symbol per line, which is **much** more readable than putting all those equality symbols on one line while they do not represent equality.  The better way would be to index you $T$ variable for each state, then you first line is $T_0 = 500$ followed by $T_1 = T_0 * 0.156048361 = 134.8206296$, $T_2 = T_1 * 0.85 = 114.5975351$...  Or you could even write only $500$ on the first line, $500  * 0.156048361 = 134.8206296$ on the second...